# How do you center an image in html while having text to the immediate left of it?

Tags: html

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>name</title></head>
<body background="bg.jpg">
<h1 align=center>About me</h1>
<center><img src="barons.jpg" height="300" width="450" vspace="20"/></center>
<h3>Basic Info</h3>
<ul type="circle">
    <li>I love to play baseball</li>
    <li>I go to - High School</li>
    <li>My favorite type of music is -</li>
    <li>I love writing computer programs</li>
</ul>
<h3>Educational Background</h3>
<ul type="circle">
    <li>I attended -</li>
    <li>I maintained a - GPA while I was there</li>
    <li>I attended - School for 6th grade</li>
    <li>I attended - school for 7th and 8th grade</li>
    <li>I now attend - School</li>
</ul>
<h3>Favorite Sports Teams</h3>
<ul type="circle">
    <li>-(Baseball)</li>
    <li>-(Football)</li>
    <li>-(Football and Baseball)</li>
    <li>-(Football and Basketball)</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to have all three unordered lists and their headers be at the same height on the page as my image, but to the left of it. I tried `<br clear="left"/>` in many places, but it didn't work.

Comment: What's wrong with your code. Try `<img style="margin:0 auto" .... />

Comment: Please post your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wrap both the text and the image into one div that you can then center. eg.

```
<div style="margin:0 auto; width:500px">
           <img src="xxx" style="float:right; width:200px;" />
           <div style="width:300px float:left;">
             Insert text here...
           </div>
  </div>
```

Obviously, you would use classes instead of inline style.

Answer (score 0):

Check the jsbin over here http://jsbin.com/zatetu/1/edit 
Check the output at http://jsbin.com/zatetu/1

**HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Jeff Koppenhoefer</title></head>
<body background="bg.jpg">
  <style type="text/css">
    .floatDiv{
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
  }
  </style>
<h1 align=center>About me</h1>
  <div class="floatDiv">
    <img src="barons.jpg" height="300" width="450" vspace="20"/>
  </div>
  <div class="floatDiv">
    <h3>Basic Info</h3>
    <ul type="circle">
        <li>I love to play baseball</li>
        <li>I go to Hilliard Davidson High School</li>
        <li>My favorite type of music is rap</li>
        <li>I love writing computer programs</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="floatDiv">
    <h3>Educational Background</h3>
    <ul type="circle">
        <li>I attended Cypress Christian School through 5th grade</li>
        <li>I maintained a 4.0 GPA while I was there</li>
        <li>I attended Tharp 6th Grade School for 6th grade</li>
        <li>I attended Weaver Middle School for 7th and 8th grade</li>
        <li>I now attend Hilliard Davidson High School</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="floatDiv">
    <h3>Favorite Sports Teams</h3>
    <ul type="circle">
        <li>St. Louis Cardinals (Baseball)</li>
        <li>Pittsburgh Steelers (Football)</li>
        <li>Davidson Wildcats (Football and Baseball)</li>
        <li>OSU Buckeyes (Football and Basketball)</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a table and adjust the pictures size and cell sizelike we learned in programming class. Hit me up if you're interested in some programming activities at school. You should know who I am.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Jeff Koppenhoefer</title></head>
<body background="bg.jpg">
<h1 align=center>About me</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><h3>Basic Info</h3>
        <ul type="circle">
            <li>I love to play baseball</li>
            <li>I go to Hilliard Davidson High School</li>
            <li>My favorite type of music is rap</li>
            <li>I love writing computer programs</li>
        </ul>
        </td>
        <td><img src="barons.jpg"/></td>
</table>
<h3>Educational Background</h3>
<ul type="circle">
    <li>I attended Cypress Christian School through 5th grade</li>
    <li>I maintained a 4.0 GPA while I was there</li>
    <li>I attended Tharp 6th Grade School for 6th grade</li>
    <li>I attended Weaver Middle School for 7th and 8th grade</li>
    <li>I now attend Hilliard Davidson High School</li>
</ul>
<h3>Favorite Sports Teams</h3>
<ul type="circle">
    <li>St. Louis Cardinals (Baseball)</li>
    <li>Pittsburgh Steelers (Football)</li>
    <li>Davidson Wildcats (Football and Baseball)</li>
    <li>OSU Buckeyes (Football and Basketball)</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```